# ImageButton Scale Type fitcenter: get no border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I want to put in an image in an ImageButton. The problem is that I've got a border around my image in my button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use plaintext for the XML portion, not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a transparent background for that like this -
`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/back_button_credits"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/backbuttonstatus"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
```

Try this